# Concatenate rows in a dataframe and delete rows based on it

Tags: python, r, subset, delete-row

I have a data frame which reads like this:

```
Column_A | Column_B | Column_C  
---------|----------|---------  
1        |  A       | ABCD  
1        | B        | ABCD  
1        | C        | ABCD  
1        | D        | ABCD  
2        | B        | BCDX  
2        | C        | BCDX  
2        | D        | BCDX  
2        | X        | BCDX  
3        | A        | ABCD  
3        | B        | ABCD  
3        | C        | ABCD  
3        | D        | ABCD
```

I then want to find out the uniques for the groupings on column_C. The output for this step would something like below:

```
Column_A | Column_B  
-------- | --------  
ABCD     | 2  
BCDX     | 1
```

This table showcases that for concatenation ABCD we have two uniques in column A for the top table

The next step for this would be assigning ABCD in column D for all the substring members for ABCD

```
Column_A | Column_B | Column_C  
---------|----------|---------  
1        | A        | ABCD  
1        | B        | ABCD  
1        | C        | ABCD  
1        | D        | ABCD  
2        | B        | ABCD  
2        | C        | ABCD  
2        | D        | ABCD  
2        | X        |     
3        | A        | ABCD  
3        | B        | ABCD  
3        | C        | ABCD  
3        | D        | ABCD
```

In the next step we need to subset out the rows which have concatenations ABCD. The output would then be:

```
Column_A | Column_B  
---------|----------  
2        |  X
```

Then as before we simply assign X in column C and the final output looks like below:

```
Column_A | Column_B | Column_C  
---------|----------|-----------  
1        | A        | ABCD  
1        | B        | ABCD  
1        | C        | ABCD  
1        | D        | ABCD  
2        | B        | ABCD  
2        | C        | ABCD  
2        | D        | ABCD  
2        | X        | X      
3        | A        | ABCD  
3        | B        | ABCD  
3        | C        | ABCD  
3        | D        | ABCD
```

The above table should be our final output. Is there an elegant way we can perform this using r/python? Please note that we have many more rows in the dataframe and would need an iterative solution for subsetting the dataframe.

Thanks

Comment: I am a newbie at R/Python and don't have much idea how to proceed ahead with this.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `tidyverse`, replace all `Column_C` by the `max` of unique groups, identify which `Column_B` are included in `Column_C` (using `grepl`) and replace the ones that don't with 'X', i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(Column_C) %>% 
 mutate(new = n_distinct(Column_A)) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 mutate(Column_C = Column_C[max(new)]) %>% 
 rowwise() %>% 
 mutate(Column_C = replace(Column_C, !grepl(Column_B, Column_C), 'X')) %>% 
 select(-new)

Source: local data frame [12 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 12 x 3
#   Column_A Column_B Column_C
#      <int>    <chr>    <chr>
# 1        1        A     ABCD
# 2        1        B     ABCD
# 3        1        C     ABCD
# 4        1        D     ABCD
# 5        2        B     ABCD
# 6        2        C     ABCD
# 7        2        D     ABCD
# 8        2        X        X
# 9        3        A     ABCD
#10        3        B     ABCD
#11        3        C     ABCD
#12        3        D     ABCD
```

I am sure that this can be more efficient If we switch the `rowwise()` operations with `map*` functions from `purrr` but I m not able to do it at the moment.